# Excel extract from employee database: delete duplicate employee data created by Cartesian join?

Tags: excel, vba

[RawData is an excel report drawn from an employee database.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1waG.png) (Tried to attach the workbook but didn't see how to do that). RawData contains multiple, unwanted duplicate items for some employees. I'm told this is because of a Cartesian join in the employee database that creates the RawData report. Whether or not that's the case, I have no control over how the RawData report is produced. It is what it is.

I need to clean up the RawData report so that the end product looks like the [CorrectedView tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkzEG.png), which I corrected manually. RawData can, at times, be several thousand rows so automating the clean-up would be a huge help.

The structure of RawData is in five groupings of columns: Employee Basic Info (cols A-E), Education (cols F-H), Awards (cols I-L), Certifications (cols M-Q) and Accomplishments (cols R-T). In the CorrectedView, what I did was:

1. Removed the duplicates for each employee in each of the five column sections
2. Moved the remaining data for each employee upward so that each employee's info begins on his/her first row
3. Removed any blank rows created between employees after doing #2 above.

I'm looking for a way to automate the process. I have some code (shown below) that accomplishes #1 for the Basic Info section but that's as far as I can get. Thanks for any help.

```
Sub DelSame()
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  For i = LastRow To 3 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then Rows(i).Range("a1:e1").ClearContents
  Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pretty much have it... use AND for multiple criteria:

```
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = LastRow To 3 Step -1
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(i - 1, 1).Value AND Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i - 1, 2).Value AND Cells(i, 3).Value = Cells(i - 1, 3).Value Then 
        Rows(i).Delete
    End If
Next i
```

---

Edit1:

So, the above suits the first grouping of columns... now for the hard part.

You can use AND sections for ALL columns, so you truly don't get any duplicates between rows (should actually fit the bill, as to not accidentally remove any items).

To get more involved, before you remove any rows, you will want to start storing values to more appropriately work with each grouping of columns, such that you work with rows a to b (untested code).

```
Dim a as Long, b as Long, i as Long, lr as Long
lr = cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row
For i = lr to 3 step -1
    If cells(i,1).value = cells(i+1,1).value then
         If a = 0 then
             a = i + 1
         End If
    Else
         If a > 0 AND b = 0 then
             b = i + 1
         End If             
    End If
    If b > 0 AND a > 0 Then
        'perform narrowed actions on range(cells(a,1),cells(b,1))
        a = 0 'resets for next grouping
        b = 0 'resets for next grouping
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Used Delete, rather than ClearContents.  Feel free to switch back if that is what you need.

Comment: Thanks and the "AND" is good reminder for multiple criteria. This snippet get's me through the first grouping of columns (A-E), but as mentioned, there are five groupings of columns stretching out to col T. The best logical order I can think of is:

Comment: @jwats I would think you would do this as nested if statements, where each of the 5 sections is reviewed.

Comment: Yes, addressing each of the sections independently is what I'm thinking but have no clue how. Name each section as a range and perform edits as long as the employee ID remains the same? (then move to the next employee) OR define a range for the employee and sub-ranges for the sections?

Comment: @jwats Gets tricky as you have different functionality with each grouping.  The first grouping is a direct comparison, though the latter sections would most likely come AFTER.  Let me give a quick snippet of code with what I'm thinking...

Comment: Glad to send the sample file if desired.

Comment: @jwats Take a look at my edit.  Since you may have random blank spaces in the latter column groupings, you will have to do some higher degree of effort to get those sorted.

Comment: Very nice routine helpful with identifying the blocks of info needed. Thanks!